# load a page with AJAX in a jQuery UI dialog without iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui

load a page with AJAX in a jQuery UI dialog without iframe

Comment: Way more details are needed. Want someone to put some effort into giving you the best answer they can to your problem?  Then put some effort into asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you **can** get the **output** of an ASP.NET page via ajax and place it in jQuery UI dialog but I wouldn't consider it **loading** an ASP.NET page in the scrict sense as no postback/callback would ever work.

Answer (score 0):

First, do your AJAX request to get the page, then put the contents in an element, then instantiate the dialog:

```
$.get('YourPage.aspx', function(html) {
    $('div').html(html).dialog();
});
```